# Unable to click on Flash object, while running scripts through Selenium Webdriver on Firefox quantum browser(version:59.0.3)

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, selenium, flash

[Flash object screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9N1I.png)Firefox disables shockwave flash plugin option to "Never Active" and "Block dangerous and intrusive Flash content" option is selected while running scripts through selenium webdriver. Because of it, **unable to click on Flash objects.**

I have tried below options but didn't work for me.

- Tried manually setting **shockwave flash plugin** option to "Always Activate" and deselected "Block dangerous and intrusive Flash content" option.
- **Used below code in configuration file.**
  profile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true");
  profile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);

**I used following code to click on the Flash object:**

```
public PublicDocuments UploadNew(string fileToUpload)
        {

            try
          {

                Wait.ForLoading(waitTime.SMALL);


                page.Element("//object[@id='SWFUpload_0']", locateBy.XPATH).GetOne().Click();



               // IWebElement we = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//object[@id='SWFUpload_0']"));


               // Point point = we.Location;
               //int xcord = point.X;
               //Console.WriteLine(xcord);
               //int ycord = point.Y;
               // Debug.WriteLine("ycord is:"+ycord);

               // // IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
               // ////js.ExecuteScript(args[0].Click(); ", we);
               //  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

               // builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//object[@id='SWFUpload_0']")), 3, 126).ClickAndHold().Build().Perform();






            }
```

Is there any other alternatives to click/enable Flash objects?

Comment: _enable_ and _click_ being two different functionalities what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want to click on the Flash Object while running the scripts but Flash object is disabled (Shockwave Flash plugins automatically set to "Never Activate" ), so i am not able to click on the Flash object.

Comment: Can you share a sample url which contains a _Flash object_ you desire to click?

Comment: While `didn't work` did you see any error? Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: **OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor** with `Java` clients? Update the question with the code trials please.

Comment: I have uploaded the code used to click on the Flash Object.

Answer (score 0):

1/ using firefox.exe -p create manualy new firefox profile
2/ run firefox with the new profile
3/ set the profile as you wish

use this code to run test in custumized profile:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
options.setProfile(selenium_profile);

options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion but it didn't work for me.